# Django : TemplateDoesNotExist at /catalog/ error

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner at django and python and i am currently stuck at [Creating our home page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Home_page) of the Django tutorial. I am getting a "TemplateDoesNotExist at error" error. I am also using windows. What am I doing wrong?

**Settings.py:**

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
import os
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY', 'cg#p$g+j9tax!#a3cup@1$8obt2_+&k3q+pmu)5%asj6yjpkag')
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', '') != 'False'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'catalog.apps.CatalogConfig', 
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'locallibrary.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'locallibrary.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

[image]

**StackTrace:**

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /catalog/
index.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/
Django Version: 2.1.5
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
index.html
Exception Location: C:\Users\AjitGoel\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 19
Python Executable:  C:\Users\AjitGoel\Envs\my_django_environment\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\AjitGoel\\django-projects\\locallibrary',
 'C:\\Users\\AjitGoel\\Envs\\my_django_environment\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\AjitGoel\\Envs\\my_django_environment\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\AjitGoel\\Envs\\my_django_environment\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\AjitGoel\\Envs\\my_django_environment\\Scripts',
 'c:\\users\\ajitgoel\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\Lib',
 'c:\\users\\ajitgoel\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\AjitGoel\\Envs\\my_django_environment',
 'C:\\Users\\AjitGoel\\Envs\\my_django_environment\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 10 Feb 2019 23:21:43 -0600
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Users\AjitGoel\django-projects\locallibrary\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\AjitGoel\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\AjitGoel\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
```

**base_generic.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  {% block title %}<title>Local Library</title>{% endblock %}
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Add additional CSS in static file -->
  {% load static %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
      {% block sidebar %}
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
          <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">All books</a></li>
          <li><a href="">All authors</a></li>
        </ul>
     {% endblock %}
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 ">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from catalog.models import Book, Author, BookInstance, Genre

def index(request):
    # Generate counts of some of the main objects
    num_books = Book.objects.all().count()
    num_instances = BookInstance.objects.all().count()    
    # Available books (status = 'a')
    num_instances_available = BookInstance.objects.filter(status__exact='a').count()    
    # The 'all()' is implied by default.    
    num_authors = Author.objects.count()    
    context = {
        'num_books': num_books,
        'num_instances': num_instances,
        'num_instances_available': num_instances_available,
        'num_authors': num_authors,
    }
    # Render the HTML template index.html with the data in the context variable
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

**index.html:**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Local Library Home</h1>
<p>Welcome to LocalLibrary, a website developed by <em>Mozilla Developer Network</em>!</p>
<h2>Dynamic content</h2>
<p>The library has the following record counts:</p>
<ul>
    <li><strong>Books:</strong> {{ num_books }}</li>
    <li><strong>Copies:</strong> {{ num_instances }}</li>
    <li><strong>Copies available:</strong> {{ num_instances_available }}</li>
    <li><strong>Authors:</strong> {{ num_authors }}</li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Show us your view method. You are using wrong template path or file name.

Comment: From your StackTrace, I can see you are referring index.html in root templates directory but django is searching your template in `catalog` directory of your templates.

Comment: Thank you, i have added the view code and the project structure.

Comment: Check my answer and follow the instructions.

Comment: nvm, i found it. Your templates folder should not be inside an additional catalog folder. It should be at the catalog folder django automatically created when you created that app or it should be at project root. Not at locallibrary -> catalog -> templates

Comment: I think @VaibhavVishal, your answer is the most correct one. If you can add it to the answers then i will accept it.

Comment: I am still getting an error where it is unable to find the static css file.

Comment: I added an answer, put your static files too as recommended in my answer, if that doesn't works, let me know what error you are getting, you might need to add some stuff in settings.py for static files

Comment: Can the downvoters explain why the question has been downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to place the template in-app level follow the directory structure like this

```
templates/<app_name>/your_template
```

Then in `view.py` use like this
return render(request, '<app_name>/your_template', context=context)

If you want to place the template in root `templates` directory follow the structure like this

```
templates/<app_name>/your_template
```

Then in `view.py` use like this

```
return render(request, '<app_name>/your_template', context=context)
```

Comment: if we go with the first option, why is Django unable to find the css file? i refer to the css file like : {% load static %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}"> in the base_generic.html page, the settings.py refers to static_url like so
STATIC_URL = '/static/'. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: you need to keep static files in your app static/css/files.css

Comment: It does not work, The app is looking for the css in the following url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/styles.css and it returns a 404 error.

Comment: you should configure [static settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/)

Comment: keep static files in project root directory /static/css/files

Comment: I got the static files working by running the server with the --insecure command i.e manage.py runserver --insecure. reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Answer (score 0):

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
```

By this line of code you are adding that templates should be in your root folder of your project. Create `templates` folder in your **root directory** of your project.

Answer (score 0):

`templates` directory in your project you should add in `settings.py` in `TEMPLATES_DIRS` like this

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/localllibrary/templates"),
)
```

what it does is it will look for your created template i.e. `index.html`  in directory specified here. If you see it is a tuple or can be a list so you add multiple directories here. `BASE_DIR` is the root of you django project that is relative not hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

You file Structure should be like this:

```
myProject
  ├── myProject
  | ├── __init__.py
  | ├── settings.py
  | ├── urls.py
  | ├── wsgi.py
  ├── myApp
  | ├── static  <-- Static files can go here
  | | ├── myApp  <-- Create a folder with the same name as the app name, recommended but not required
  | | | ├── css
  | | | | ├── style.css
  | | | ├── js
  | | | | ├── some.js
  | ├── templates  <-- Templates can be here
  | | ├── myApp  <-- Create a folder with the same name as the app name, recommended but not required
  | | | ├── index.html
  | | | ├── other.html
  | ├── __init__.py
  | ├── models.py
  | ├── urls.py
  | ├── views.py
  ├── templates    <-- Templates can be here too
  | ├── sometemplate.html
  ├── static  <-- Static files can go here too
  | ├── css
  | | ├── somecss.css
  | ├── js
```

Now if your templates/static files is inside the templates/static folder at your project root, you can refer to them easily as `someplace.html` or `css/somecss.css`.
While if it's inside  the template folder in your app like this:

```
myApp --> templates --> myTemplate.html
```

Then you can use it like this: `myTemplate.html`. But it's recommended to create another folder inside the templates folder with app name to avoid confusion, like this:

```
myApp --> templates --> myApp --> myTemplate.html
```

Now you will refer to it like this: `myApp/myTemplate.html`, it avoids confusion as you will know from which app template is coming from, also it makes it possible to have templates with same name(say `index.html` or `base.html`) in multiple apps. Same goes for static files.